# JavaScript Testing Inputs

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, mocha.js

I have some JavaScript functionality that reads values from inputs on he current page.  These are selected using some custom attributes.

I want to write tests to prove that this is working correctly using [mocha](http://visionmedia.github.io/mocha/)

My question is, which is the better route to take

1. create inputs on the page that shows the mocha test results?
2. try to mock an object to act as the current page?

Answer (score 0):

Depends on your code. Most of the time you will use jquery to get the data from the input fields. Then its easier to to create the input fields in the DOM for your tests, cause its not that easy to mock jquery in that case. You have to mock the `$` first, which must return an object with `val` function.

You could also rewrite your code that the function you wanna test always get the data as parameter inject, instead of reading them from input fields.

At the end getting data from the DOM is mostly the same as using the `new` operator in function you wanna test or using global variables, which should be avoided for better testability.